# Setting an Appbar in Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-appbar

In flutter app whenever i use navigation a totally new screen appears, is it common that on navigating a totally new screen appears and appbar and drawer of of previous screen disappear or I am doing something wrong?

These is the way I navigate :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>const Screen2()))
```

or

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Screen2()))
```

By using these methods, I need to provide a appbar to every screen I navigate to. Is there any other method that I can use to only navigate the body part keeping the appbar and drawer same(not even rebuild)?

Comment: This can done be with nested navigation => https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav

Comment: is your second page have appbar and other settings or not ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve appbar and sidenav, i typically just exchange the body of the scaffold on some view change, and reserve navigator routing for views that dont need an appbar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  const SampleWidget({Key? key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SampleWidget> createState() => _BaseWidgetState();
}

class _SampleWidgetState extends State<SampleWidget> {

  List<Widget> _views = [
    View1(),
    View2(),
    View3(),
  ]
  int _currentView = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Widget'),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          height: 150,
          child: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.help)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _currentView = index;
              });
            },
          )
        )
      ),
      body: _views[_currentView],
    );
  }
}
```